# Javascript regex split on = that aren't between curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split over = in a string except for those in curly brackets.
I tried:

```
s.split(/(=)+(?=[^{}]*(\{|$))/g);
```

but doesn't works;

### EXAMPLE:

```
 "ciao2={this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}"
```

***should be:***

```
 ["ciao2","{this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}"]
```

Comment: You have nested curly braces, regex won't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split(/=(?=\{)/);`  as

```js
console.log(
  "ciao2={this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}".split(/=(?=\{)/));
```

Comment: Note that this answer is not the direct answer to the question. `=(?={)` only matches a `=` that is followed with `{`.

Answer (score 1):

Will the next RegExp work for you?

```
"ciao2={this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}".match(/^(.*)=({.*})$/);
```

This returns:

```
[ 'ciao2={this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}',
'ciao2',
'{this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}',
index: 0,
input: 'ciao2={this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}' ]
```

Comment: This splits inly into two fragments. It can split on `=` inside braces, e.g. `"{a={b}}"`, and not sure why you require braces after the `=`.

Comment: To be sure you are splitting in the right =, but not necessary idd.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it using regex? Just write a trivial parser.

```js
function parse(str) {
  var arr = [],
      current = [],
      nestLevel = 0;
  for(var ch of str) {
    if(ch === '=' && !nestLevel) {
      arr.push(current.join(''));
      current.length = 0;
    } else {
      if(ch === '{') ++nestLevel;
      else if(ch === '}') --nestLevel;
      current.push(ch);
    }
  }
  arr.push(current.join(''));
  return arr;
}
console.log(parse("ciao2={this.onclick;this.ciao=function(){ciao}}"));
```

Consider throwing if `nestLevel` becomes negative.